# Match an expression but don't match lines that start with a #

Tags: c++, regex, qregularexpression

I am us Qt. I have a text string that I specifically look for a function call `xyz.set_name()`, I want to capture the last occurrence of this call but negate it if the line that contains it starts with a `#`. So far I got the regex to match the function call but I don't know how to negate the `#` matched lines and I don't know how to capture the last occurrence, don't know why all the matches are put into one capture group.

```
[().\w\d]+.set_name\(\)\s*
```

This is what I want it to do

```
abc.set_name() // match
# abc.set_name() // don't match
xyz.set_name() // match and capture this one
```

Update for more clarification:

My text read like this when printed out with qDebug

```
Hello\nx=y*2\nabc.set_name()   \n#xyz.set_name()
```

<s>It's is a long string with `\n` being as newline.</s>

Update: a longer test string for test. I have tried all the suggested regex on this but they didn't work. Don't know what is missing.
https://regex101.com/r/vXpXIA/1

Update 2: Scratch my first update, the `\n` is a `qDebug()` thing, it doesn't need to be considered when using regex.

Comment: You example shows the first line being matched but not captured and the last line being both matched and captured. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Use `(?s).*\n(?!\h*#)\h*([\w().]+\.set_name\(\))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9zviz/2/)

Comment: Further to my first comment, you can only match a substring. You cannot  match two substrings separated by a substring that isn't matched. In your three-line example you could match all three lines (the entire string) and capture the last line or match just the last line, in which case there would be no point in capturing it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merely want to match the last line that matches the pattern

```
^[a-z]+\.set_name\(\)
```

you can use the regular expression.

```
(?smi)^[a-z]+\.set_name\(\)(?!.*^[a-z]+\.set_name\(\))
```

For simplicity I've used the character class `[a-z]`. That can be changed to suit requirements. In the question it is `[().\w\d]`, which can be simplified to `[().\w]`.

Note that since the substring of interest is being matched there is no point to capturing it as well. The fact that one of the lines prior to the last one begins with `'#'` is not relevant. All that matters is whether the lines match a specified pattern.

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/556k9G/2/)

The PCRE regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?smi)                  : set single-line, multi-line and case-indifferent
                          modes  
^                       : match the beginning of a line
[a-z]+\.set_name\(\)    : match 1+ chars in the char class, followed
                          by '.set_name\(\)'
(?!                     : begin negative-lookahead
.*^[a-z]+\.set_name\(\) : match 0+ chars (including newlines), the  
                          beginning of a line, 1+ letters, '\.set_name\(\)' 
)                       : end negative lookahead
```

Recall that single-line mode causes `.` to match newlines and multi-line mode causes `^` and `$` to match the beginning and ends of lines (rather than the beginning and end of the string).

Comment: Hi, my text string is a long string of the whole text with `\n` being as newline. Your regex couldn't find any match.

Comment: TIL Negative lookahead. Nice!

Comment: reddy, the text I used at the link in my answer was `abc.set_name()\n# abc.set_name()\nxyz.set_name()\n`, and as you see, `xyz.set_name()` was matched by the regex. I don't understand why you don't get the same result if you are using the same test string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Hi I have updated the first post with a longer string for testing

Comment: The problem stems from the way test cases are entered at regex101.com. To enter the string `"Hello\nWorld"` you need to put `Hello` on one line and `World` on the next line. There will then be an unseen newline after `Hello`. regex101 will read that as `"Hello\nWorld"`. When you enter `Hello\nWorld` on one line regex101 reads `\n` as two characters, not as an escaped `"n"`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/1R6ugG/2/)

Comment: I got it to work, thanks. I also got confused by qDebug() where it output the string with `\n` and I thought I have to take that into account. `(?smi)^[().\w]+\.set_name\(\)(?!.*^[().\w]+\.set_name\(\))`. I'll update the first post to not confuse future people.

Comment: It would be better to not confuse both existing and future people. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need the regex lookahead operators (if your regex engine supports it). This [will work](https://regex101.com/r/nRRN0s/6).

```
(?(?=^[^#])(^\s*[a-zA-Z]+\.set_name\(\))|z^)
```

---

Explanation:

- `(?(?=patt)then|else)` - Regex if-else construct, if regex matches given pattern `patt`, `then` is matched, otherwise `else` is matched
- `patt` = `^[^#]` -- at the start of the line, no `#`
- *then part* - if `patt` is true -- `^\s*[a-zA-Z]*\.set_name\(\)` matches any number of whitespace followed by `<something>.set_name()` where `something` is variable name.
- *else part* -- If `patt` is false -- match `z^` which is z coming before start of line, which isn't possible.

---

Edit: just realised you can have digits in variable names (but it cannot start with one). In that case, improved regex (not tested)

```
(?(?=^[^#])(^\s*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\d]*\.set_name\(\))|z^)
```

---

Edit: Since you also have newline characters in your string, it doesn't match the problem description in your question. Nevertheless, simple enough to deal with by just tokenising the string.

Just split up the strings based on new line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream isr;
    isr.str("I am John\n today is  \n#abc.set_name()\n");
    std::string tok;
    std::vector<std::string> vs;
    while(std::getline(isr, tok))
    {
        std::cout << tok << std::endl;
        vs.push_back(tok);
    }
    
    for (auto r_it = vs.rbegin(); r_it != vs.rend(); ++r_it)
    {
        std::cout << *r_it << std::endl;
        // if match then break from loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi my text string read like this when print with qDebug: `I am John\n today is  \n#abc.set_name()\n`, with `\n` as newline. Your regex didn't return any match.

Comment: Check edit @reddy . Also it **SHOULD NOT** match right? because of `#` ?

Comment: Yes, don't match line that starts with `#`

Comment: I forgot that you wanted the last match. Made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?s).*\n(?!\h*#)\h*([\w().]+\.set_name\(\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z9zviz/2/), your match is in Group 1. **Details**:

- `(?s)` - DOTALL mode on, `.` now matches any chars
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- `\n(?!\h*#)` - a newline that is not immediately followed with 0 or more horizontal whitespaces and then a `#` char
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `([\w().]+\.set_name\(\))` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[\w().]+` - 1 or more word chars, `)`, `(` or `.`
  - `\.set_name\(\)` - a `.set_name()` string.

Comment: Hi this doesn't match a string with just `abc.set_name()`

Comment: Hi I have updated the first post with a longer test string, please take a look

Comment: @reddy OK, so it may be the first line, then use https://regex101.com/r/Z9zviz/5m or https://regex101.com/r/vXpXIA/2